# How to Create a line break in WhatsApp messages [ReactJS Web]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, whatsapi

I'm trying to send a message from ReactJs to Whatsapp api But i can't create a content text with line break :
ex:

```
Hello Shop,
I'm looking for this Shoes. Can you help me ?
--Name
```

This is my code that i tried with :

```
   <button onClick={
     () => window.open("https://wa.me/phoneNumber?text="Hello Shop,'\n'
      I'm looking for this Shoes. Can you help me ? '\n'
     --<Name>")}>
       Send Message
   <Button>
```

I tried with : `'\n', '\r\n\r\n', '%0a', '%0D%0A',...` But did not work.

Comment: You can try string literals as an alternative. `   `

Comment: yes i did, but its still working

Answer (score 1):

linebreaks are "normaly" encoded by `\n` (LF), `\r\n` (CRLF).

for http GET parameters you also need to use urlencode.

```
line1="hello"
line2="world"
msg = encodeURIComponent(`${line1}\r\n${line2}`)
```